# How do I loop through a string in makefile?

Tags: shell, makefile

I want to write a Makefile that will iterate through a string and print it word by word.

Here is what I did in the Makefile:

```
MINION="fou foo bar"
test:
    @for n in $(MINION); do \
        echo "$$n"; \
    done
```

Actual output:

```
fou foo bar
```

What I want to get is:

```
fou
foo
bar
```

I also want to iterate on sentences that has a whitespace and coma separator, ex. "fou, foo, bar"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Makefile variables do not use the same assignment syntax as shell variables. `MINION="foo fou bar"` will assign the string `"foo fou bar"` to the `MINION` Makefile variable, which will then be substituted into the shell command line as `for n in "foo fou bar"`.

Use instead

```makefile
MINION = foo fou bar
```

Comment: that MINION variable comes from gitlab-ci.yml file wich somtimes send some vraibles in this format "fou, foo, bar" ? what can be done in this case?

Comment: If you are using GNU make, you can use its functions to strip any quotes.